# How to change language of achievements in Google Play Games

Tags: languages, localization, google-play-games

I have an issue with achievements in Google Play Games.

I've noticed this when playing Clash of Clans (but it's not limited to it. Every game that has Russian translation of achievements is affected).
I used to use Russian language in the game and my Google account.
Now my Google account and system language is set to Ukrainian, and the language of the game is set to English. Google Play country is set to Ukraine.
However, Play Games continues to show achievements in Russian.
I can't find how to change it.

I've already asked for the help from the community, but got no answer after more than a week:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/251211195

Comment: Have you installed the [Google Play Games](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.play.games) Android app on your device?  Where are you checking the information?  For example, what is displayed online in [Google Account > My Activity (Filter: Google Play Games)](https://myactivity.google.com/activitycontrols/webandapp?hl=en&utm_source=my-activity&product=45)?

Comment: You mentioned that you changed your system language and Account language. Can you provide more detail as to how/where this was done?  Also, you could [edit] your question to include your Google Play country. You can find that in the **Google Play Store** app click on your **profile picture**, then choose **Settings** (2nd-last option, right before **Help & feedback**) then select  **General** and then **Account and device preferences**.  Under **Country and profiles** it will list your Google Play country.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the app. The link you've sent shows everything in English.

Comment: My system language was always Ukrainian, I've only changed the language of Google account via the settings through a browser